# How can I hide rows in a VirtualRepeater?

Tags: webos, palm, enyo

I'm using one VirtualRepeater in Enyo (WebOS 3.0):

```
{kind: enyo.VirtualRepeater, name: "eventList", onSetupRow: "setupRowWithEvent", onclick: "doListTap", components: [
   {kind: enyo.Item, name:"eventItem", layoutKind: enyo.HFlexLayout, tapHighlight: true, components: [
       /* components of every row: inside a Enyo.Item */       
   ]} 
]}                                 
/* more code */
setupRowWithEvent: function(inSender, inIndex) {
     if (somethingIsTrue) {

         return true;    
     }
 }
```

What I want to do is:

- if something is true, render the row
- if not, show nothing
  The problem is that now it's showing empty rows, instead of nothing. It shows rows with content and empty rows, but I want no rows. I can't return false, or the VirtualRepeater will stop rendering rows.

Comment: Solved!To hide the items in a VirtualRepeater, you only have to set the showing property to false. That, is, in my case:this.$.eventItem.setShowing(false);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I've found is simple:

```
{kind: enyo.VirtualRepeater, name: "eventList", onSetupRow: "setupRowWithEvent", onclick: "doListTap", components: [
    {kind: enyo.Item, name:"eventItem", layoutKind: enyo.HFlexLayout, tapHighlight: true, components: [
        /* components of every row: inside a Enyo.Item */       
    ]} 
]}                                 
/* more code */
setupRowWithEvent: function(inSender, inIndex) {
  if (somethingIsTrue) {
      // code to update every row 

  } else {  // we don't want this row to show
      this.$.eventItem.setShowing(false);
  } 
 return true; // if you don't return true, the virtual Repeater stops fetching rows
}
```